# React Native: createBottomTabNavigator screenOptions doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Hi am working on my tab navigator, so far so good until I tried to customize the tab navigator by adding icons and customized the colors:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import CategoriesScreen from '../screens/CategoriesScreen';
import CategoryMealsScreen from '../screens/CategoryMealsScreen';
import MealDetailScreen from '../screens/MealDetailScreen';

import FavoritesScreen from '../screens/FavoritesScreen';

import HeaderButton from '../components/HeaderButton';
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import { CATEGORIES } from '../data/dummy-data';

import Colors from '../constants/colors';

const MealsNav = createStackNavigator();

const MealsNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <MealsNav.Navigator
            mode="modal"
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }}
        >
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="Categories"
                component={CategoriesScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'Meals Categories'
                }}

            />
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="CategoryMeals"
                component={CategoryMealsScreen}
                options={({ route }) => {
                    const catId = route.params.categoryId;
                    const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find((cat) => cat.id === catId);

                    return {
                        title: selectedCategory.title,
                    };

                }}
            />
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="MealDetail"
                component={MealDetailScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'Meal Detail',
                    headerRight: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Favorite'
                                iconName='ios-star'
                                onPress={() => console.log('Mark as the favorite')}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    ),
                }}
            />
        </MealsNav.Navigator>
    );
};

const MealsFavTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator();

const MealsTabNav = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <MealsFavTabNavigator.Navigator>
                <MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                    name="Meals"
                    component={MealsNavigator}
                    screenOptions={() => ({
                       tabBarIcon: (tabInfo) => {
                          return <Ionicons name="ios-restaurant" size={25}  color={tabInfo.tintColor} />
                       }
                      })}
                      tabBarOptions={{
                        activeTintColor: 'tomato',
                        inactiveTintColor: 'black',
                      }}
                />
                <MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                    name="Favorites"
                    component={FavoritesScreen}
                    screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                        tabBarIcon: (tabInfo) => {
                           return <Ionicons name="ios-star" size={25}  color={tabInfo.tintColor} />
                        }
                       })}
                       tabBarOptions={{
                         activeTintColor: 'tomato',
                         inactiveTintColor: 'black',
                       }}
                />
            </MealsFavTabNavigator.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};


export default MealsTabNav;
```

As you can see here, I tried to add a screenOptions:

```
const MealsFavTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator();

const MealsTabNav = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <MealsFavTabNavigator.Navigator>
                <MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                    name="Meals"
                    component={MealsNavigator}
                    screenOptions={() => ({
                       tabBarIcon: (tabInfo) => {
                          return <Ionicons name="ios-restaurant" size={25}  color={tabInfo.tintColor} />
                       }
                      })}
                      tabBarOptions={{
                        activeTintColor: 'tomato',
                        inactiveTintColor: 'black',
                      }}
                />
                <MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                    name="Favorites"
                    component={FavoritesScreen}
                    screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                        tabBarIcon: (tabInfo) => {
                           return <Ionicons name="ios-star" size={25}  color={tabInfo.tintColor} />
                        }
                       })}
                       tabBarOptions={{
                         activeTintColor: 'tomato',
                         inactiveTintColor: 'black',
                       }}
                />
            </MealsFavTabNavigator.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

The icons doesnt work even the colors doesnt work and there are no errors on the console. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenOptions prop is used for navigators not screens.

When using for screens you will have to use 'options' not screenOptions

```
            <MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                    name="Favorites"
                    component={FavoritesScreen}
                    options={({ route }) => ({
                        tabBarIcon: (tabInfo) => {
                           return <Ionicons name="ios-star" size={25}  color={tabInfo.tintColor} />
                        }
                       })}
                />
```

Also the tabBarOptions should be moved to navigator

```
<MealsFavTabNavigator.Navigator  
       tabBarOptions={{
                        activeTintColor: 'tomato',
                        inactiveTintColor: 'black',
                      }}>
```

Comment: how about tabBarOptions? activeTintColor? where do I put those?

Comment: Updated the answer, as its a common property it should be at navigator level